# Delete metrics in prometheus 1.4

Tags: prometheus

We have prometheus running, we would like to delete old data from prometheus data source, we are using data retention.

Prometheus version 1.4.1

How can we delete the data with out affecting prometheus?

Answer (score 5):

In Prometheus 2.7+, you can pass the `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` flag running Prometheus. By default, data older than 15 days will be deleted.

If you are on 2.6 or older, you can rely on the `--storage.tsdb.retention` flag.

If you are still on version 1, you can rely on `--storage.local.retention`.

*This might not be exactly the answer to the original question and it's almost a year old but since people might find it searching for this problem, the answer might be useful to some*